# Set servo limits from PWM signal with 2 potentiometers and no microcontroller

Tags: servo

sorry if this has been answered before or if this is something really naive/impossible. my experience is mainly with SW dev and I am trying to do this for an RC car so here it goes:

Turns out I have a servo that is connected to a receiver, this servo unfortunately goes by default beyond the min / max angle that I need (hence it starts to make a buzz).

I want to ask if its possible (and how) to given the same pwm signal from the receiver and an intermediate circuit with 2 potentiomenters (one for the min and one for the max angle) limit the angle the servo moves.

So lets say if I get the PWM signal that moves between 60 - 120 deg, with the intermediate circuit that I am trying to do I want to limit this on the min to be 70 and on the max to be 110.

so the signal and voltage will still come from the RC receiver and will be connected to said circuit and then the output of the circuit will go to the servo with the set limited angles by the potentiometers.

I have been reading over the internet and learning about servos and how they work; I know that you can control a servo with a potentiometer with the 555 circuit and even with an arduino and whatnot but what I need is to limit the pwm signal that already comes from the receiver in the minimum space possible. Any thoughts?

Again, sorry if this is a naive question, this is not my area of expertise.

Comment: The pwm is used to drive your motor, actuator, or what have you. To be a servo, there must be a feedback loop, where something in or attached to your motor, actuator or what have you, sends a signal back indicating it's actual position. What is that signal in your case? Do you have access to it? Do you have a schematic circuit diagram of what exists now?

Comment: This is a job for a small microcontroller. Measure the duty-cycle of the incoming PWM, limit it to whatever you need, then regenerate it.

Comment: This is a severely impractical complexity/calibration nightmare to do in analog circuitry, and I speak from having tried essentially that as an analog high-rate ESC in my youth.  Use an MCU!  A modern computerized transmitter would also allow you to fix this at that end; there are some open source firmwares for reflashing...

Comment: What is generating the transmitted signal?

Comment: guys, thanks for the comments, answering:

@MathKeepsMeBusy: Unfortunately I dont have the diagram as of right now, as mentioned I have been checking schematics for the 555  but they dont do what I am trying to achieve, let me be straight: I am trying to limit the servo angles for the differential locks on a TRX4 Landrover RC Car since they move past the limit and they start to buzz. The signal pretty much comes from the RC Receiver in the car (which is sent from my RC transmitter through a switch). (hope it answers your comment).

Comment: @brhans with a microcontroller would be a piece of cake for me, but I need something small since the space in the car is limited hopefully something like Receiver -> wire -> shrink tubing with 2 small potentiometers  for HW -> wire to servo

Comment: @BruceAbbott The receiver from the RC (that is sent from my controller from a physical switch).

Comment: @ChrisStratton could be, hence asking for feedback/thoughts. I dont think I can reflash the TRX4 transmitter :/

Comment: A micro controller will be by far the physically smallest solution to this problem.  And yes, people do put things like SOIC ATtiny's and PICs in heatshrink in wiring harnesses - eg, someone sent me one to convert brushed motor PWM back to a servo signal to feed a brushless ESC in a tiny helicopter (though reflashing the ESC itself would have been better).  And you can rig up some training scheme so you don't need the potentiometers.  But also consider the *traditional* solution to this problem, which is to to connect the linkage further in on the servo horn.

Comment: @ChrisStratton oh then this is great news!, could you suggest me any kit, small enough that I can put intro a shrinking tube? I was looking into https://www.hobbytronics.co.uk/microchip-18f14k22-soic but this is not something I can program directly.  The servo linkage would not work since the horns for the diffs are on a set position (But love that idea of the tiny pic!). I would imagine then that if there is no such thing as a small plug and play kit I can figure out how to set it up to programm it. Thanks! :)

Comment: It's been ages since I worked with a PIC, more familiar with something like the ATtiny85 but would assume they have similar.  What I'd do is start with something where you can get it all sorted out with an 8-pin DIP on a breadboard and then switch to the same part in an 8-pin SOIC package with 30 gauge silicone wire and tiny heatshrink on the pins.  Or you may actually have enough room for a breakout or the DIP...

Comment: @ChrisStratton thanks!, I will follow that route, ATtiny85 would also work, just need to get a small prototype with a breadboard and a way to program it, then I can move to SOIC as you said. I think that would work. Thanks a lot! :D

Comment: There are guides for using an ATtiny as a mini-Arduino programmed by a real one.  They work with non-Arduino code, too.  In fact you can even use Arduino's copy of avr-gcc and avrdude, and for the latter turn on verbose mode to see what commands you'd need to issue.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in several comments, it seems the best way would be to use a microcontroller that would be sufficiently small to make it fit inside a heatshrink tube and be in between the receiver and the servo!.